# How do I add multiple numerical values that I got from previous algorithms into an array to do some calculation in MU python editor for microbit?

Tags: python, arrays, bbc-microbit, mu

I'm new to programming and I'm building an ultrasonic sensor to calculate the distance of an object from the microbit. I have written some codes to measure the distances 50 times in 1 sec, but since each measurements are slightly different, i want to find the mean of all 50 measurements using an array with the distances as elements. How do i add all 50 measurements into the array? Here is the code i have written so far.

```
from microbit import *
from machine import time_pulse_us
from utime import sleep_us

trig = pin2
echo = pin1

i = 0
while i <= 50:
    trig.write_digital(0)
    echo.read_digital()
    trig.write_digital(1)
    sleep_us(10)
    trig.write_digital(0)
    time = time_pulse_us(echo, 1)
    distance = (time/2) / 29.1
    print(distance)
    sleep(20)
    i += 1
```

Comment: What's the connection to JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

ukBaz gives a good and thorough [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64495545/24447). Another method would be to keep a running total of all the readings. Once you have 50 readings, divide this total by 50.

With only 50 samples, this method is no real advantage over that shown by ukBaz, where the samples are stored in a list before averaging. If you have a large number of samples, keeping a running total instead of using a list can save RAM. The microbit v1 does not have a lot of RAM.

Please find a code snippet below to illustrate the idea.

```
NUM_SAMPLES = 50
...
distance = 0
for i in range (NUM_SAMPLES):
    distance += fake_distance()
distance = distance / NUM_SAMPLES
```

As an aside, the signal to noise ratio for a measurement is improved by the square root of the number of samples taken. So taking 50 measurements improves the signal to noise ratio over a single measurement by about a factor of 7.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is that you create a list of values and then average those values.
Below I have modified your example to do that. I create an empty list called `all_readings` and then append each new reading to it. Once we have the 50 readings, then I average all the values in the list.

I have made a few other changes to your code which I hope you find helpful.

1. Put the code to read the value from the sensor into a function as helps identify which bits of the code is doing what
2. As I don't have the sensor attached to my micro:bit, the `read_distance` function wasn't working so I created a new function called `fake_distance` so I could test my `average_reading` function
3. Created a function called `average_reading` to do the averaging
4. Used a `while True` loop so that the readings will continue forever
5. Created a for loop that will read the sensor 50 times before averaging the values

When you run it on your micro:bit with the sensor you can delete the line:

`all_readings.append(fake_distance())`

and uncomment (remove the `#`) from the line above that one

```
from microbit import *
from machine import time_pulse_us
from utime import sleep_us
from random import randint

display.show(Image.HAPPY)

trig = pin2
echo = pin1

def fake_distance():
    return randint(0, 9)
    
def read_distance():
    trig.write_digital(0)
    echo.read_digital()
    trig.write_digital(1)
    sleep_us(10)
    trig.write_digital(0)
    time = time_pulse_us(echo, 1)
    return (time/2) / 29.1

def average_reading(readings):
    return sum(readings) / len(readings)
    
while True:
    all_readings = []
    for i in range(50):
        # all_readings.append(read_distance())
        all_readings.append(fake_distance())
    avg = average_reading(all_readings)
    display.show(avg)
    print(avg)
    sleep(20)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still not good with using functions so this method actually helped me understand how to use it better.